# OpenIAM set up using docker for custom edition

Tags: docker

I need to install and set up OpenIAM custom edition using docker in centos VM , I don't want to go for enterprise edition for which docker image is available in OpenIAM git hub through a subscription.

I am aware of the rpm install manually for custom edition that requires other dependencies to install as well for complete set up, but want to automate this through docker. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

Just for transparency, I work for OpenIAM.

Our RPM installation requires minimal external dependencies.  Additionally, there will be a new release of the Community Edition next month which will be provided via Docker as well.  The Enterprise Edition currently supports RPM, Docker and Kubernetes.

We will also be releasing a slew of tutorial videos for v4.1.11 and 4.1.12 in the coming weeks to help users get started.

Regards,

Ameet Shah

OpenIAM